# ListView: deleting a row by it's owner when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView that displays comments for an article.
Each comments has a button that, when clicked, deletes that comment provided that the logged person is the comment's owner or an administrator.

I need a way of storing comment's ID in the ListView somehow and then I need to check if the ID of the comment's author is the same as the ID of the logged user (which is stored in the Session) and then, if they match, display the button that deletes the comment when clicked.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify DataKeyNames attribute on the ListView markup and then get the DataKey in the button click event

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView" DataKeyNames="CommentId" ...
```

and in button click event, you can get the id

```
(int)myListView.DataKeys[itemIndex]["CommentId"]
```

or get commentId in fourth ListItem

```
int commentId = (int)myListView.DataKyes[3]["CommentId"];
```

**Edit, as you mention your requirements further**

You can access the current item being bind to list view in ItemDataBound event

Just add the ItemDataBound event attribute on ListView mark up, and do your logic within the event

```
<asp:ListView onitemdatabound="myListView_ItemDataBound" runat="server" ID="myListView" ...

protected void myListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        int commentId = (int)DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CommentId");

        // get author id based on comment id

        // or if you have auther id within the datasource
        // by which you are binding the listview then

        int ID_Author = (int)DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "ID_Author");

        // get a reference to the delete button in the item
        // for instance you may do by this
        Control delete_button = e.Item.FindControl("deleteButtonId");

        // will hide if the author id don't match with the session id
        delete_button.Visible = ID_Author.Equals((int)Session["loggedin_userId"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so that pulls the comment's id from the current row. Now I need to check somehow if the comment's attribue ID_Author is equals to the ID (stored in session) of the logged user and then display, or not, the button. Any ideas?

Comment: @barjed, you can do this type of logic in ItemDataBound event of the ListView; as I added the sample code for you.

Comment: I think that it should have been dataItem.DataItem in the Eval statements. At least, that is how it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In ItemDataBound event of the ListView, you can get hold of the data item bound to the ListView. This object will have all the ID's that you require.

For processing the click event, you will need ItemCommand event. The ID of the article can be passed as command argument by the Delete button.

Hope it helps.